# how to calculate shipping cost with discount

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to solve a homework problem where I input a price, weight, and distance to work out the total cost for a customer. The problem I have is I need to apply a discount based on how far the distance is for example 500 miles = 15% discount, but when I tried I break my code. see attached the code.

```
base = float(input("How much is the base price?: "))
weight = float(input("What is the weight?: "))
distance = float(input("What is the distance?: "))

if distance <250:
    discount += 0% # no discount
elif distance >= 250 and distance <= 500:
    discount += 10% # 10 % discount
elif distance >= 500 and distance <= 1000:
    discount += 15% # 15% discount
elif distance >= 1000 and distance <= 2000:
    discount += 20% # 20% discount
    elif distance >= 2000 and distance <= 3000:
    discount += 35 % # 35% discount
elif distance >= 3000:
    discount += 50% # 50% discount

sum = base * weight * distance *(1 - discount)
print("The shipping cost is: ",sum)
```

I need to use the equation sum = baseprice * weight * distance * (1 - discount).

thanks in advance

Comment: If you pasted your code correctly, you just need to unindent the `elif distance >= 2000 and distance <= 3000:` line. Also remove the '%' character and simply divide those values by 100.

Comment: `10%` is an invalid way to define a `float`. Since percent is just division by 100, do that instead: `discount = 0.1`. Also don't call your variable `sum` -- it shadows the builtin python function `sum()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the changes needed:

- `10%` -> `0.1`
- `+=` -> =
- Wrong indent on one of `if`s
- Remove `and`s

`10%` is not a valid format, use values between 0 and 1 instead.

Since `discount` is not getting added to (it is defined), `=` should be used.

Since your are using `elif` there is no need to add `and` check.

Here is a working code:

```py
base = float(input("How much is the base price?: "))
weight = float(input("What is the weight?: "))
distance = float(input("What is the distance?: "))

if distance <250:
    discount = 0 # no discount
elif distance >= 250:
    discount = 0.1 # 10 % discount
elif distance >= 500:
    discount = 0.15 # 15% discount
elif distance >= 1000:
    discount = 0.20 # 20% discount
elif distance >= 2000:
    discount = 0.35 # 35% discount
elif distance >= 3000:
    discount = 0.5 # 50% discount

sum = base * weight * distance *(1 - discount)
print("The shipping cost is: ",sum)
```

Comment: Happy to help. I also forgot to mention `and`s issue in original answer. I added that as well.

Answer (score 0):

Remove % and divide by 100 to get percentage. += have a different purpose. I don't think that is what is your requirement here. you can read about that with examples  here https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/assignment-operators-in-python/
Also when you have `and distance <= 500` in 1st elif `and >= 500` in the 2nd condition, 1st conditional discount will be applied. This code should work:

```
base = float(input("How much is the base price?: "))
weight = float(input("What is the weight?: "))
distance = float(input("What is the distance?: "))
# discout = 0
if distance < 250:
    discount = 0 # no discount      
elif distance >= 250 and distance < 500:
    discount = 10 # 10 % discount
elif distance >= 500 and distance < 1000:
    discount = 15 # 15% discount
elif distance >= 1000 and distance < 2000:
    discount = 20 # 20% discount
elif distance >= 2000 and distance < 3000:
    discount = 35  # 35% discount
elif distance >= 3000:
    discount = 50 # 50% discount

total = base * weight * distance * (1 - (discount/100))
print("The shipping cost is: ",total)
```